# Is OPC UA the best way of change data from many individual systems from several domains?

Tags: interop, middleware, opc-ua

When I need interoperate several systems, exists different middleware as possibility to support this process. However, in OPC-UA is not clear for me if is necessary apply some one between these systems. Someone can support me, how is made this process in OPC-UA, please.

For example: 
Systems A with language C and operational system (OS) windows, TCP-IP, Systems B with language java, OS Linux, UDP, and 
System C with language python, OS IOS, TCP-IP

How OPC-UA interoperate these systems, using middleware or they can be connected directly using implementation in interface with OPC.

Thanks

Comment: No, it is not appropriate everywhere.  OPC is almost exclusively used in industrial automation.  It requires a support system, people that are aware of the hardware requirements and what to do when the system misbehaves.  Always talk to the customer first.

Comment: If you don't have OPC-UA I would say don't use it -- this is because there is one major flaw in its design. No matter what network protocol you use OPC-UA servers are free to mangle your data. So since you use TCP/IP and it guarantees the order it would mean you don't use this trait which IMHO is pretty important. Of course one could wrap each data package with some time-envelope to force the order, but come one, it is much better to use another approach or write one from scratch.

Comment: Thank for all. I understood your explanations. This system is being planned to agricultural domain, have you some knowledge abou what have been used in this domain without be MQTT that is protocol of IoT. Once Systems-of-Systems have different behavior  than it.